# Anapanasati in Pali script

Tags: anapanasati, pali

Does anyone know how Anapanasati is written in Pali script? I failed to find a dictionary online that could give the correct script form.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean with correct diacritics?  Pali doesn't have it's own script.  It was written down in whatever alphabet happened to be available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Anapanasati Sutta in Pali is here: https://suttacentral.net/pi/mn118

It appears there is no Pali script, per the comment made to the question:

> Emperor Ashoka erected a number of pillars with his edicts in at least
>   three regional Prakrit languages in Brahmi script, all of which
>   are quite similar to Pali. Historically, the first written record of
>   the Pali canon is believed to have been composed in Sri Lanka, based
>   on a prior oral tradition. As per the Mahavamsa (the chronicle of Sri
>   Lanka), due to a major famine in the country Buddhist monks wrote down
>   the Pali canon during the time of King Vattagamini in 100 BC. The
>   transmission of written Pali has retained a universal system of
>   alphabetic values, but has expressed those values in a stunning
>   variety of actual scripts. In Sri Lanka, Pali texts were recorded in
>   Sinhala script. Other local scripts, most prominently Khmer, Burmese,
>   and in modern times Thai (since 1893), Devanāgarī and Mon script (Mon
>   State, Burma) have been used to record Pali. Since the 19th century,
>   Pali has also been written in the Roman script. An alternate scheme
>   devised by Frans Velthuis, called the Velthuis scheme (see § Text in
>   ASCII) allows for typing without diacritics using plain ASCII methods,
>   but is arguably less readable than the standard IAST system, which
>   uses diacritical marks.
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pali#Writing

---

> ‘Pāli’ is not a language, it is the name of the mūla (source)
>   Tripiṭaka text, as distinguished from its commentary, which is called
>   Aṭṭhakathā - this distinction between Pāli and Aṭṭhakathā only makes
>   sense in the commentarial tradition - it was not (and should not be)
>   used as the name of the language.
>
> The language of the Theravāda tripiṭaka is actually an artificially
>   standardized (sanskritized) form of the original buddhist canon, which
>   was written in the early Kharoṣṭhī script (only fragments of which
>   survive today). Kharoṣṭhī was greatly unsuitable for writing sanskrit,
>   and that is why sanskrit words written in Kharoṣṭhī appears like
>   another language altogether (which is broadly called Middle-Indic, but
>   is known by specific modern names like Pāli & Gāndhārī based on the
>   script they are written in).
>
> The oldest script in use was Kharoṣṭhī. The second-oldest script was
>   Brāhmī. Sanskrit was written initially in Kharoṣṭhī (which did not
>   distinguish between long and short vowels, conjunt consonants and
>   simple consonants etc). So it became very difficult to read texts
>   written in this script, even today western scholars are breaking their
>   heads over whether Kharoṣṭhī texts are really in sanskrit or some new
>   language (which in 1946 some have named as Gāndhāri, although such an
>   independent language was never recognized at any point of time in BCE
>   India). Anyways an improved script arose which was called Brāhmī
>   (which did distinguish between short and long vowels) but still did
>   not enable writing conjunct consonants properly (and scholars have
>   named this language an early version of Pāli, which again was never
>   known by that name in ancient India). With the passage of a few
>   centuries, Brahmi was perfected for sanskrit, but the old ways of
>   writing (which we call Gāndhāri & Pāli today) did not die out, they
>   kept evolving into what became independent languages called the
>   prākṛta languages (or prākrits)
>
> https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-script-of-pali-language

---

> The Kharosthi script, also spelled Kharoshthi or Kharoṣṭhī, is an
>   ancient script used in ancient Gandhara and ancient India
>   (primarily modern-day Afghanistan and Pakistan) to write the Gandhari
>   Prakrit and Sanskrit. It was popular in Central Asia as well. An
>   abugida, it was in use from the middle of the 3rd century BCE until it
>   died out in its homeland around the 3rd century CE. It was also in
>   use in Bactria, the Kushan Empire, Sogdia and along the Silk Road,
>   where there is some evidence it may have survived until the 7th
>   century in the remote way stations of Khotan and Niya.
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kharosthi

Comment: Oh, wow. Interesting, so there's no actual written text script for Pali. It's an oral language only, written in other languages' text.

Comment: thanks. it looks like that is the case. it was new news to me, also, regards

Answer (score 0):

Use commentary to translate it:

Ānāpānassatikathā in http://www.tipitaka.org/romn/cscd/e0101n.mul8.xml

For the concentration meditation parts (first 4 parts form 16 parts):

> Herein a monk — having gone to the wilderness, to the shade of a tree,
>   or to a bodily seclusion building — sits down folding his legs
>   crosswise, holding his body erect and setting mindfulness to the fore
>   [lit: breathes at nose tip]. Always mindful, he breathes in; mindful
>   he breathes out.
>
> 1. "When he breathing in long, he contemplates 'I breathing in long';
>      Or when he breathing out long, he contemplates 'I breathing out
>      long'.
> 2. When he breathing in short, he contemplates 'I breathing in short';
>      Or when he breathing out short, he contemplates 'I breathing out
>      short'.
> 3. He trains himself 'I am breathing in and sensitively contemplating
>      the entire breath in'. Or he trains himself 'I am breathing out and
>      sensitively contemplating the entire breath out'.
> 4. He trains himself 'I am breathing gentle breath in'. Or he trains
>      himself 'I am breathing gentle breath in'.

cr. http://tipitaka.wikia.com